# Shoutcast sc_serv admin.cgi json fields

Tags: shoutcast, internet-radio

When I receive a response from my sc_serv admin.cgi shoutcast server, I am wondering what the two fields represent. Particularly, the `type` and `grid` fields. The following json is what is returned when I request listeners info. I am unable to find anything on shoutcast docs about these fields.

```
{
  hostname: '34.88.65.135',
  useragent: '**EMPTY**',
  connecttime: 129910,
  uid: 143440,
  type: 1,
  referer: '',
  xff: '',
  grid: 143440,
  triggers: 0
}
```

Thank you in advance, for your response.